# Linkedin API SignUp Button - I am a beginner

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, intercom

I am making a website for the first time. I am sorry for any dumb question but I really have no background. However, I am trying to learn. 
I developed the website on Weebly (www.i2i.network) and I am trying to include a LinkedIn SignUp button through their API service to monitor the people who are using the website.

So far I copied and pasted what I have found on the LinkedIn SDK guide

```
<script type="in/Login"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    IN.User.logout(callbackFunction, callbackScope);
    api_key:   [API] //I put my API key here 
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    lang:      [LANG_LOCALE]
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

</script>
```

The button appeared the first time and it opens the connection to my LinkedIn profile. That's exciting! :D (Geek)

At this point I still don't know if I retrieve any data from the LinkedIn API service and if "yes" how to manage them and possibly include them in Intercom.io.

As far as I understood I should receive from LinkedIn API the following:

```
{
  "firstName": "Frodo",
  "headline": "Jewelery Repossession in Middle Earth",
  "id": "1R2RtA",
  "lastName": "Baggins",
  "siteStandardProfileRequest": {
    "url": "https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=…"
  }
}
```

Do I actually receive the answer? How do I read it? How do I use it in the following Intercom.io script?

```
<script>
  window.intercomSettings = {
    app_id: "k9sz4pfb",
    name: "Nikola Tesla", // Full name
    email: "nikola@example.com", // Email address
    created_at: 1312182000 // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
  };
</script>
<script>(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/k92zopfb';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()</script>
```

I know this might be a very basic question but I am starting from zero and I like to learn by practicing...

Furthermore, if you have any suggestion about website or tutorial where I could learn step-by-step it will be really appreciated.

Thank you for your help,

Giacomo

Comment: If your code is working properly, a recruiter will appear after the button click event has fired.

Comment: @snowYetis: Can you be more specific? What is a recruiter? An example would be useful. :S

Comment: My first comment is a joke. Have you used browser DevTools before? Launch your web page and click F12. Next, click your LinkedIn Submit button and see if anything appears in the Console tab.

Comment: @snowYetis You scared me! Ok I used web inspector. I basically have two lines:

`[Error] Blocked a frame with origin "https://api.linkedin.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.i2i.network".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.`

`Object
firstName: "Giacomo"
headline: "Bla Bla Bla"
id: "BayoIbrFpn"
lastName: "Carloni"
siteStandardProfileRequest: Object
__proto__: Object`

Comment: @snowYetis Now I know I receive the info. How do I read it? And how do I use it in a different script?

Comment: I am typing a solution now, before I answer, are you using Node.JS?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/ Node JS is a great way of handling data using JavaScript. Once you feel more comfortable with JQuery check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the syntax but this should get you started.

```
// Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
 function getProfileData() {
    var dataOutput = 


      // I added the callback event DONE. This assures the data method is called when the this API call is successful and complete.
     var dataOutput =    IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError).done( {

       if (dataOutput != null) {
          DoSomethingWithYourData(dataOutput);
       }
    });

 }

  function DoSomethingWithYourData(dataOutput) {
    console.log(dataOutput);
    // Parse your data or assign it to a control. do whatever here.
 }
```

And to answer your other question, you can add this to a JS script file and reference it on other pages, but you would have to keep any control IDs/class names added to this script file the same, so my tip would be to keep this file very generic so that it does not depend on anything else and only deals with working with LinkedIn's data.

I recommend these links for further reading so that you can expand on your code.

[Jquery Parse JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

[JQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[JQuery Callbacks](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/)